# add json root to jmsserializer

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I know you can use the `[xml_root_name][1]` when working with XML. Is there a way to accomplish this with JSON as well?

Currently my XML looks like the following:

```
<user id="13">
    <username>dadams</username>
    <email>email@example.org</email>
</user>
```

And I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "username": "dadams",
    "email": "email@example.org"
}
```

When I really want this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 13,
        "username": "dadams",
        "email": "email@example.org"
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember you would need to serialize an array. Something like this: `array('user' => $userObject);`.

Comment: if i do that, the XML is changed as well

Comment: is the user a part of collection or just main object bing returned? I found supporting XML with JMSSerializer really painful in some cases.